# TypeError : cannot read property 'method' of undefined in nodejs Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am developing a simple chat application using node.js and socket.io. When I am connecting to the socket.io then I face an error of "cannot read property 'method' of undefined".

Here is the app.js file code:-

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path')
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    session = require('express-session')
    config = require('./config/config.js'),
    ConnectMongo = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.dbURL),
    passport = require('passport'),
    FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
    rooms = [] ;
    
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname , 'views'));
 
 app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));   
  
 app.set('view engine', 'html');
  
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
  
 app.use(cookieParser());
  
 var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  
 if(env === 'development'){
     // dev specific settings
     app.use(session({secret:config.sessionSecret, saveUninitialized : true, resave : true}));
       
  } else {
      //Production specific settings
      app.use(session({
         secret : config.sessionSecret,
         saveUninitialized : true,
         resave : true, 
         store : new ConnectMongo({
            // url : config.dbURL, (for Avoiding two seperate connection)
             mongooseConnection:mongoose.connections[0],
             stringify : true
         })
      })); 
  }
  
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  
  require('./auth/passportAuth.js')(passport , FacebookStrategy , config , mongoose);
  
  require('./routes/routes.js')(express,app ,passport , config);
   
 
 /* app.listen (3000 , function(){
    console.log("ChatUp working on the Port 3000"); 
    console.log('Mode:'+ env);
 }); */
 
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 
 
 
 var server = require('http').createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
 
 require('./socket/socket.js')(io,rooms);
 
 server.listen(app.get('port' , function(){
     console.log('Chat Up on Port : '+ app.get('port'));
 }))
```

And Here is my Chatrooms.html srcipt :-

```js
$(function() {
  var host = '{{config.host}}';
  var socket = io.connect(host + '/roomlist'); //   http://localhost:3000/roomlist

  socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connection Established .. !');
  })
})
```

JSON file contain "host":"http://localhost:3000"

But when I run the code there is an error :TypeError : cannot read property 'method' of undefined

Console Error :-

> c:\Users\ANKUR SINGH\Desktop\node\Chat App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138
>     debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
>                                   ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
>       at Function.handle (c:\Users\ANKUR SINGH\Desktop\node\Chat App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:33)
>       at EventEmitter.handle (c:\Users\ANKUR SINGH\Desktop\node\Chat App\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:173:10)
>       at Server.app (c:\Users\ANKUR SINGH\Desktop\node\Chat App\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:38:9)
>       at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at emitListeningNT (net.js:1263:10)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:444:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)
>       at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:432:11)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

How to get rid of this error. ??

Picture of : /router/index.js file :-

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jds5o.png)

Comment: where you see this error?

Comment: When I run the app using Window CMD :- node app.js

Comment: It appear in the console : TypeError : cannot read property 'method' of undefined

Comment: so, do you see any additional info? like line where is error?

Comment: plzz Help me #Grundy

Comment: try see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588057/typeerror-cannot-read-property-handle-of-undefined-if-fn-handle-fn-se)

Comment: Same error. Nothing happen

Comment: so, just check value variables that you use and see what is _undefined_

Comment: I am not getting it , what you trying to say?

Comment: in your code you use a few variables, like: _cookieParser_, _config_, _session_ and also pass, for example to `use` function _session(...)_. So just check this values before using, like: `if (!session) console.log(...)` and etc

Comment: Can you show the `router/index.js` code? Also, this code has parsing errors such as missing between in variable declarations at the top of `app.js`

Comment: Ok, so it looks like `req.method` is undefined. This probably means you forgot to set it properly in some middleware you are using. Go through the code from the start of the route, put breakpoints and check does `req.method` get set at any point. If it doesn't then that's your error. If it does, then check where it gets reset back to undefined.

Comment: #nem you may say right but I don't know how to correct it. Because router/index.js file is the internal core. And I have no such enough idea about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After 9 hours of continuous struggling. I have the found the solution of my question.

The error code :-

```js
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000 );

server.listen(app.get('port' , function(){
     console.log('Chat Up on Port : '+ app.get('port'));
 }));
```

And the Correct code :-

```js
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  
  server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Updated : Server listening at port %d', port);
  });
```

The reference link is:-
[Correct Code reference](http://code.runnable.com/VBiUCRpPOs5cbBr4/simple-socket-io-chat-for-node-js-and-hello-world)

Comment: That actually wasn't necessary. All you were missing from your code was that you had `server.listen(app.get('port' , function(){...`, when you should have had `server.listen(app.get('port') , function(){...`. You forgot to close the app.get('port'). I know because I just had the same issue :).

Answer (score 3):

Your code would work. There is a missing ')'

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000 );
server.listen(app.get('port') , function(){
console.log('Chat Up on Port : '+ app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using app.js as express and start.js as the "npm start", all you have to do is to make sure the application was exported `module.exports = app;` and on the start.js you just have to require the module `require('./app')` this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing some commas when declaring your variables?

```
path = require('path')
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
session = require('express-session')

path = require('path'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
session = require('express-session'),
```

Comment: Ya you are right but still same problem. Same Error come

Comment: Have you checked the value of req before line 138 of the index.js? Proto.handle must be being passed null as the first arg.

Comment: If you have time to check my code and error then you can check at my github link

Comment: You need to follow the call stack leading up to the call to Proto.handle.

Comment: I follow and find that req=undefind in every call stack (local variable)